# monitoring the listview to slide to the bottom

Tags: android

i get the data from the Internet and show in the listview,i want to  make it come true that when i slide the screen with my finger and if the listview is to slide to the bottom ,i will get more data from the Internet and update the adapter of the listview.But how can i monitor the listview to slide to the bottom,there seems no functions in the SDK api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the 'AbsListView.OnScrollListener' interface, that's what you're looking for. Implement it, then register the implementing class with your ListView. With the paramteres you get when you scroll, you can detect if the user reached the bottom of the ListView. Then, you simply download more content from the Net, and update the adapter. Remember to call 'notifiyDatasetChanged()' after adding stuff to the adapter.